# Gitlab maven output directory

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using Gitlab for CI/CD.

Basically I have a project with 2 branches.
Branch A and B and both have **.gitlab-ci.yml** which do maven install and copy the output jar file to a remote server, two branches will copy it in different remote servers.

Below is my sample **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
build:
  stage: build
  tags: 
      - myrunner
  script:
      - mvn clean install
      - cp /root/myrunner/my/project/target/*.jar /remote/server/
```

The problem is that, both projects are in the same runner directory when build, so there's a possibility to clash and overwrite the target directory.

I understand that I can change the runner for the other branch so that the path will be different but what if I have 10 branches for that project?
Is there a way to specify the build directory of the runner like something below?

**/root/myrunner/my/project/branchname/target/**

Answer (score 0):

My advice will be to use a [Gitlab Runner with Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html).

This way, each job will be executed in a different container and there is no clash possibility.